# On the functoriality of scalar extensions of local rings (edited)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, local-rings

**Note.** *I have edited my question to make it more transparent, following some very good comments that I received. I am sorry if it is a bit long.*

A local homomorphism of local rings $(A,\mathfrak{m})\stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow}(B,\mathfrak{n})$ is called a *scalar extension* (terminology due to Hans Schoutens) if:

- $\varphi(\mathfrak{m})B=\mathfrak{n}$, and
- $\varphi$ is a flat extension.

Let's fix a field $K$ (algebraically closed, if you wish) and let $\mathscr{C}_K$ be the category of Noetherian local rings whose residue field is a subfield of $K$, with morphisms being local homomorphisms.

**Question A.** Is there a *functorial* way of producing scalar extensions with a prescribed residue field? More precisely, is it possible to define a functor $F_K:\mathscr{C}_K\rightarrow\mathscr{C}_K$ in such a way that for every $A\in\mathscr{C}_K$ the local ring $F_K(A)$ is a scalar extension of $A$ with residue field $K$?

*Here are some things that I know about this question:*

**(1)** Grothendieck proved that scalar extensions with prescribed residue field always exist:

**Theorem.** (EGA III, Proposition 10.3.1, page 20). *Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be Noetherian local ring with residue field $k$, and let $K$ be a field extension of $k$. Then there exists a scalar extension $(A,\mathfrak{m})\stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow}(B,\mathfrak{n})$ from $A$ to a Noetherian local ring $B$, with the property that $B/\mathfrak{n}$ is $k$-isomorphic to $K$.*

Grothendieck's construction of the desired scalar extension depends on various 'choices' that he makes in his proof, and hence, does not produce a unique answer. For this reason I think it is hopeless to get a functor there.

**(2)** Various mathematicians have used a different method to construct scalar extensions with prescribed residue field, which seems 'more hopeful' to be functorial. In [b] (pp. 776-777) Kunz calls a special case of this construction *the constant field extension*. A version of this construction in the equicharacteristic case appears in [a] (pp. 18-19, 6.3). A more detailed description of this method can be found in [c] (pp. 4-7) and in [d] (pp. 36-38). I describe it in the equicharacteristic case: Given a local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ and a field extension $K$ of $k$, take a coefficient field $k\hookrightarrow\hat{A}$ and complete $\hat{A}\otimes_kK$ with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak{m}(\hat{A}\otimes_kK)$. This is your $F_K(A)$. It is easy to see that this $F_K(A)$ is an scalar extension of $A$ with residue field $K$. ($F_K(A)$ depends on the choice of a coefficient field of $\hat{A}$, but is unique *up to* isomorphism).

**Question B.** Is the $F_K(\:\cdot\:)$ that was just described a functor from $\mathscr{C}_K$ to $\mathscr{C}_K$? To clarify the question, if $A_1\stackrel{\psi}{\longrightarrow} A_2$ is a local homomorphism of Noetherian local rings in $\mathscr{C}_K$, then does $\psi$ extend to a local homomorphism $B_1:=F_K(A_1)\rightarrow B_2:=F_K(A_2)$?

I can see how the method described in [c] provides an affirmative answer in equicharacteristic $0$ to Question B (it comes down to the fact that in equicharacteristic $0$ every maximal subfield of a complete local ring is a coefficient field) but I don't see how the method of [c] would still work in equicharacteristic $p>0$. I haven't checked the mixed characteristic case, yet, because I thought the equicharacteristic case is easier and if it cannot be settled positively, then there is even less hope for the mixed characteristic.

**References.**

**a.** M. Hochster and C. Huneke, *$F$-regularity, test elements, and smooth base change*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., **346** (1994).

**b.** E. Kunz, *Characterizations of regular local rings of characteristic $p$*, Amer. Jour. of Math., **41** (1969).

**c.** H. Schoutens, *Classifying singularities up to analytic extensions of scalars*, Ann. of Pure and Applied Logic, **162**, (2011) (also available on the Arxiv, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508236)).

**d.** H. Schoutens, *The use of ultraproducts in commutative algebra*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, **1999**, Speringer (2010).

Comment: Even if your detailed question would be answered with *yes*, this does not mean that we get a functor: There must be "compatible" choices of the extensions.

Comment: The answer to the detailed question is no, take $A_1=A_2=B_2=\mathbf Z_{(p)}$, $B_1=\mathbf Z_p$, $k_1=k_2=K=\mathbf F_p$.

Comment: @ a-fortiori: Thank you for the example, but I don't think it answers my question. I think your example is not obtained using the described constructions, otherwise, if you take $A_1=A_2$ and $k_1=k_2=K$ and apply the *same* method to construct extensions $B_1$ and $B_2$, you will not get two different answers. $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not two arbitrary scalar extensions, they are the ones obtained by applying what I like to call a 'functor'. Note that scalar extensions are far from being unique.

Comment: @ Martin: I think you are right, for some reason I assumed it was clear that I was not talking about *any* two scalar extensions. The second reference (by Schoutens) gives a detailed method of constructing such extensions. I was implicitly assuming that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are obtained by applying that construction to $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: The existence of a local homomorphism $\hat A_1^K\to\hat A_2^K$ is a special case of the weak universal property of Schoutens's *completion of* $A_1$ *along* $K$. Regarding the functor question: which category should be the domain?

Comment: I don't see how you can restrict attention to a particular constructino of scalar extensions.  E.g. suppose given $A_1$, and let $A_2$ be a randomly constructed scalar extension with residue field $k_2 := K$.  Then surely $B_2 = A_2$, and so your are looking for a map $B_1 \to A_2$, i.e. a map from your (or Schouten's) particular scalar extension to my randomly constructed one.  This more or less means (I think) that you are asking for Cohen rings to be functorial, which they are not (as far as I know). 

Comment: @ a-fortiori: That's a good question. Let's restrict our attention to the following category as our domain: fix an algebraically closed field $K$ and consider the category of all Noetherian local rings whose residue fields are subfields of $K$, with morphisms being local ring homomorphisms. So, our "functor" is always completion along K, which we have fixed.


Comment: @ a-fortiori: Regarding the existence of a local homomorphism, I agree it must follow from the universal property, however, in his proof of the universal property in the equicharacteristic case, on page 7 he writes "Since $S$ is complete, we can find an embedding $l\rightarrow S$ which agrees with the subfield $k$ of $l$ with the composition $k\rightarrow\widehat{R}\rightarrow S$. I see how this is true in equicharacteristic $0$, you extend the image of $k$ in $S$ under $\widehat{R}\rightarrow S$ to a maximal subfield and that's a coefficient field $l$, but I don't see this in equichar. $p>0$.

Comment: @ Emerton: The part that you assume $B_2=A_2$ is not for sure, unless your randomly constructed scalar extension $A_2$ is $\mathfrak{m}_2$-adically complete. In the equicharacteristic case the construction (for $B_2$) is as follows: take a coefficient field $k_2\hookrightarrow\hat{A}_2$ and complete the tensor product $\hat{A}_2\otimes_{k_2}K$ with respect to the ideal $\mathfrak{m}_2(\hat{A}_2\otimes_{k_2}K)$, where $\mathfrak{m}_2$ is the maximal ideal of $A_2$.
 

Comment: @ Emerton: The last part of your comment is also interesting. I see how we would get a functor if Cohen rings were functorial. But is it clear to you that what I am asking for would require Cohen rings to be functorial?

Comment: In what follows, I am referring to the preprint version (v2): You are right, there seems to be a problem with this part of the paper. As in Eisenbud Exercise 7.17b take a complete local noetherian ring $S$ containing a maximal subfield $\kappa$ which is not a coefficient field. Let $\lambda$ be the residue field of $S$ and take $R=\kappa$ for simplicity. Then, $\kappa\to S$ cannot be extended to $\lambda$ since $\kappa$ was assumed maximal.

Comment: Another problem: Take an arbitrary field $\kappa$ and let $R=\kappa$. The author's construction yields $\hat R^\lambda=\lambda$, but in the case $S=\lambda$ there are several non-isomorphic $\kappa$-homomorphisms $\lambda\to\lambda$ in general.

Comment: I can certainly take $A_2$ to be a complete local ring.  A concrete example would be to take $A_1 = \mathbb Z_p$, to take $K$ to be a non-perfect extension of $\mathbb F_p$, and to take $A_2$ to be some randomly chosen Cohen ring for $K$.  Then $B_1$ will be (I imagine, because I can't think what else it would be) some particularly constructed Cohen ring, and you are asking for a map $B_1 \to B_2 = A_2$, which is tantamount to asking for a functorial identification of any two Cohen rings for $K$.

Comment: @ Emerton: But I think in your example *there is* a map $B_1\rightarrow B_2$, by Theorem 29.2 in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory* (page 224). On the other hand, I see your point. So I need to think more about this example and get back to you.

Comment: In the definition of $\mathscr C_K$, is the embedding of the residue field into $K$ part of the data, and are the morphisms supposed to be compatible with it? When you say that $F_K(A)\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr C_K)$ should be a scalar extension of $A$, do you just mean that there exists a $\phi\colon A\to F_K(A)$ making $F_K(A)$ a scalar extension, or do you actually want a natural transformation $\mathrm{id}_{\mathscr C_K}\to F_K$? If Question B is read in this sense, Eisenbud's example still applies.

Comment: @ Emerton: Are your Cohen rings of characteristic $0$ by definition, or do you allow Cohen rings of characteristic $>0$ as well?

Comment: @ a-fortiori: Yes, in addition to $A\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}F_K(A)$ being a scalar extension, I also need to have a commutative diagram
$$A_1\stackrel{\psi}{\longrightarrow}A_2$$
$$\downarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow$$
$$F_K(A_1)\stackrel{\overline{\psi}}{\rightarrow}F_K(A_2)$$
The particular embedding of the residue field in $K$ is not part of the data, I think for a given pair of $A_1$ and $A_2$ any choice of embeddings of residue fields that would give an answer is good for me. I don't really need $F_K(A_1)\stackrel{\overline{\psi}}{\rightarrow}F_K(A_2)$ to be unique.

Comment: @ a-fortiori: Regarding the Eisenbud example, what $K$ are you using in $F_K(\:\cdot\:)$? Some overfield of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: I was thinking about the mixed characteristic case, but I'm not sure whether my reservations apply in equichar. cases too.   It just seems to me (and this is just an impression, and could be wrong) that the kind of thing you are asking for is close to asking that Cohen rings be functorial, for the reasons I've sketched above.   

Comment: I just read a-fortiori's answer below, and it precisely illustrates the kind of problem I was worried about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post this as an answer since it is too long, actually answers Question B and sheds some light on Question A. The example is taken from Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra*, Exercise 7.17b.

Let $A_1=\mathbf F_p(t)$, $A_2=\mathbf F_p(u)[[x]]$, $\psi\colon A_1\to A_2$, $t\mapsto u^p+x$. On the residue fields, $\psi$ induces an isomorphism $\mathbf F_p(t)\cong\mathbf F_p(u^p)$. If $K$ is any extension field of $\mathbf F_p(u)$, the $F_K$ in Question B has $F_K(A_1)=K$ and $F_K(A_2)=K[[x]]$ with the obvious homomorphisms $A\to F_K(A)$. However, the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \mathbf F_p(t) & \xrightarrow{\psi} & \mathbf F_p(u)[[x]] \\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\
K && K[[x]]\end{array}$$
cannot be completed since $t$ becomes the $p$-th power $u^p$ in $K$, whereas it is mapped to $u^p+x$ in $K[[x]]$ which is not a $p$-th power.

As for Question A, depending on the exact interpretation, any $F_K$ should satisfy $F_K(k)=K$ for subfields $k\subset K$, so this example shows that $k[[x]]\to F_K(k[[x]])$ cannot just be the canonical homomorphism $k[[x]]\to K[[x]]$ in general.

EDIT: The above assumes, contrary to what you said in the comments, that the embedding of the residue field into $K$ is part of the data in $\mathscr C_K$. Otherwise, you can still apply the same argument if you assume $K$ algebraically closed (so that the image of $t$ is still a $p$-th power). However, I think that in this case even the simpler problem of choosing a natural embedding into $K$ for all fields in $\mathscr C_K$ is already impossible except in trivial cases.

Comment: Nice (counter-)example! I am convinced that (as noted by a-fortiori) even if we allow choice of embedding of the residue field into $K$, it may still be impossible to extend the homomorphism. 

*Big thank you to a-fortiori and Emerton for taking their time to discuss this problem with me.*